# UI Boostrap accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, web-frontend

Tried really hard to solve this simple problem. Have an accordion with several sections. The problem I am having is that I want the top accordion section to be expanded by default but, since the data in the different sections is being populated from api calls, if the sections below the top section return data after the top section, they contract or collapse the top section. Iam able to make the sections below the top section not expand and simulate a mouse click when the top section has loaded to expand it but, once again if the data come back from sections below it collapses top section.

This is the code for one section of my accordion:

```
    <accordion>
    <div class="zone zone-aside-right">



            <div data-ng-controller="SelectUserController" id="account-group-widget">
                <accordion-group class="sp-sidebar-module">
                    <div>
                        <accordion-heading>
                            <h3 class="h4 sp-sidebar-module-header">
                                <a id="headerRelatedContacts" href="javascript: void(0);" data-ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen"><i id="iconRelatedContacts" class="icon-refresh icon-spin"></i>@mycontact.text</a>
                            </h3>

                        </accordion-heading>
                        <div class="sp-sidebar-module-content" ng-cloak>
                            <ul id="account-groups-list" class="sp-account-groups">
                                <li class="" ng-repeat="x in contacts">
                                    <div>
                                        <h4 style="display: block; width: 50%; float:left" class="h4 sp-account-group-name"><b>{{x.clientTaxonomy}}</b></h4>
                                        <h4 style="display: block; width: 50%; float:left" class="h4 sp-account-group-name">{{x.fullname}}</h4><br>
                                        <h4 style="display: block; width: 50%; float: left" class="h4 sp-account-group-name">{{x.contactdata}}</h4><br>
                                        <h4 style="display: block; width: 50%; float:left" class="h4 sp-account-group-name"><a href="mailto:{{x.contactemail}}">Contact me</a></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: -30px" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/_images/RelatedContacts/default.jpg"))'"
                                             src="@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/_images/RelatedContacts/{{x.userclientcode}}.jpg"))" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </accordion-group>
            </div>
<accordion>
```